# Initilaize reactive form with the data get from service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am working on angular project.I am stuck at problem where I am fetching data in service subscribing there and passing that data using behaviour Subject.
Now in my component I am subscribing service and getting data and trying to prepopulate my form but I am getting error

**service.ts**

```
  publicpost= new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

 getPublicPost(){
    this.http.get<UPost[]>(`https://write-your-heart-out-b338b.firebaseio.com/post/${this.uid}/public.json`)
    .pipe(
      map(responseData => {
        const postsArray: UPost[] = [];
        for (const key in responseData) {
          if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key] });
          }
        }
        return postsArray;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(posts => {
      this.publicpost.next(posts)


      this.combine()
    });
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
 constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public acrud: ACrudService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,

  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
    .subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        console.log(params)
        this.id = +params['id'];
        this.posttype=params['type']
      });

   this.acrud.getPublicPost()
this.PubicPost()
 this.EditForm()
}

PubicPost(){
 this.isFetching=true
  this.allSub = this.acrud.all.subscribe(d => {
      this.allPost = d
      this.isFetching=false
      console.log("####################", this.allPost)
     ,
    err=>{
      this.error=err
    },
    ()=>{
      console.log(this.allPost[this.id].title) // this part is not execution dont know why
      this.exampleForm.patchValue(
        {
          title:this.allPost[this.id].title
        }

      )
    })
}

EditForm() {

    this.exampleForm = this.fb.group({
      imgurl:['', Validators.required],
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      desc: ['', Validators.required],
      category: [this.selected, Validators.required],
      subcategory: ['  ', Validators.required],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      privacy: ["true"],

    });
```

**Approach2:**

```
PubicPost(){
 this.isFetching=true
  this.allSub = this.acrud.all.subscribe(d => {
      this.allPost = d
      this.isFetching=false
      console.log("####################", this.allPost)

  console.log(this.allPost[this.id].title)
      this.exampleForm.patchValue(
        {
          title:this.allPost[this.id].title
        }

      )
     ,
    err=>{
      this.error=err
    })
}
```

**Approach3:**

```
PubicPost(){
 this.isFetching=true
  this.allSub = this.acrud.all.subscribe(d => {
      this.allPost = d
      this.isFetching=false
      console.log("####################", this.allPost)
      this.EditForm() // removing this method from ngOninit and Initiliazing here
      )
    err=>{
      this.error=err
    })
}
```

The only way I am able to get data is by using interpolation in HTML template like

```
 <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="comment">Title:</label>
            <div class="input-style">
                <input placeholder="Name" class="form-control" formControlName="title"
                value={{Allpost[this.id].title}}>
          </div>
</div>
```

Also here is ther image of my cconsole log
[image]
 I can see tht my console is coming blank  with blank array for the first time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getRawValue() to read all values from a formgroup and the patchValue() to write all values at once:

```
// write into form
const raw = {
  imgurl: 'demo',
  title: 'demo',
  desc: 'demo',
  category: 'demo',
  subcategory: 'demo',
  name: 'demo',
  privacy: true
};
this.formGroup.patchValue(raw);
```

and

```
// read from form:
const raw = this.formGroup.getRawValue();
```

If you want to get all http results at once, you could use forkJoin:

```
forkJoin([
    this.http.get<X>(url1),
    this.http.get<whatever[]>(url2),
    this.route.params
]).
subscribe(
    arr => {
        console.info(arr[0]);
        console.info(arr[1]);
        console.info(arr[1]);
    }
)
```

See: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Don't forget to unsubscribe:   https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f

Comment: But my subject is not emitting all the vlaue at once instead I am gettingthree console log so How should i give my last subject vlaue to the form controls